# Wordpress fee payment gateway based per user role

Tags: wordpress

This thing make me crazy. 
i need to implemet a method like this

get_user_role > get_payment_gateway > if(some user AND payment condition) > apply some discount

Is it possible? I havent find nothing similar, have you any idea?

Anoter way can be to duplicate the payment gateway, i need to have 2 Bank transfer and two paypal payment gateway, and after hidden one to some user and apply the discount, is it possible, how i can implement this?

PS the duplication of the paymanet gateway can be a very interesting and easy solution, because after i can use a lot of plugin that do what i want.